# Is it possible to write replaceAll-regex in some other format?

Tags: java, regex

The code I have:

```
String stringTxt = "Hello World!!";
String negatorStr = "Loop";
String regexToUse="["+negatorStr.toLowerCase()+negatorStr.toUpperCase()+"]";
System.out.println(stringTxt.replaceAll(regexToUse, ""));
```

As you can see form the code, the objective is to replace "L" or "O" or "P" with "" (empty). And the code makes `negatorStr` case-insensitive by expressing it in lowercase and uppercase and combining both within " [ ", " ] " to turn it into a regular expression compatible with `replaceAll()`.

**Question:** Is there any other way to make `negatorStr` case-insensitive so that I can use it in `replaceAll()` ?

Comment: 10 second google search : https://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/case_insensitive_matching_in_java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are two ways.

Either use the inline flag:

```
final String replaced = myString.ReplaceAll("(?i)[lop]", "");
```

Or use a `Pattern` and `Matcher` with explicit flags:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[lop]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
final String replaced = p.matcher("Hello World!!").replaceAll("");
```

Output:

```
He Wrd!!
He Wrd!!
```

Comment: Whats an inline flag?

Comment: The inline flag is the `(?i)` at the start. This is usually used to that you can make _parts_ of a pattern case insensitive but it can be used in this way too.

Comment: Or should it be _Flag Inline_ ? Java docs refer (?i) as `embedded flag expression (?i)`

Comment: Embedded is an synonym for inline in this case.

Comment: @boxed__l Incidentally, [here's a really good article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) on the power of inline flags.

Answer (score 3):

Use `(?i)` at the beginning of your regex to make it case insensitive.

It would be

```
String regexToUse = "(?i)[" + negatorStr + "]";
```

You can check out other possible flags in the Field Summary of the [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(?i)` in your regex or use a Pattern and [the Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE flag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE):

```
String regexToUse = "[" + negatorStr.toLowerCase() + "]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexToUse, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
System.out.println(p.matcher(stringTxt).replaceAll(""));
```

The latter makes sense if you replace several strings with the same pattern otherwise the former is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

> the objective is to replace "L" or "O" or "P" with "" (empty)

```
String stringTxt = "Hello World!!";
System.out.println(stringTxt.replaceAll("(?i)(l|o|p)", ""));
```

Comment: Why not a character group, i.e. `[lop]`?

Comment: one more way.. just another way ?

Comment: Just seems overkill to user a capturing group with a logical OR to match different individual chars. In fact this is exactly what the character class is for so it could even be considered bad practice...